# Calling Webservice from adobe process

Tags: web-services, adobe, livecycle, livecycle-designer

I am calling Webservice from adobe process .
my wsdl contains web method "storeDocument" which takes Document as input.

```
<xs:element name="storeDocument">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element xmlns:java="java:org.w3c.dom" name="req" type="java:Document"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="storeDocumentResponse">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="return" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

but when i generate request in webservice setting. it shows

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:res="http://resourceusage.resource.domain.services.nyss.ktv.tdc.com" xmlns:java="java:org.w3c.dom">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <res:storeDocument>
         <res:req>
            <java:XmlStandalone>?</java:XmlStandalone>
            <java:XmlVersion>?</java:XmlVersion>
            <java:StrictErrorChecking>?</java:StrictErrorChecking>
            <java:DocumentURI>?</java:DocumentURI>
         </res:req>
      </res:storeDocument>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I dont have idea how to invoke this service , i tried to give

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:res="http://resourceusage.resource.domain.services.nyss.ktv.tdc.com" xmlns:java="java:org.w3c.dom">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <res:storeDocument>
         <res:req>
            <java:StrictErrorChecking>false</java:StrictErrorChecking>
            <java:DocumentURI>{$ /process_data/@outputForm $}</java:DocumentURI>
         </res:req>
      </res:storeDocument>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But it is not working
it gives me error

```
     <bea_fault:stacktrace xmlns:bea_fault="http://www.bea.com/servers/wls70/webservice/fault/1.0.0">com.bea.xml.XmlRuntimeException: java.lang.InstantiationException: org.w3c.dom.Document

    at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.ClassLoadingUtils.newInstance(ClassLoadingUtils.java:137)

    at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.ByNameRuntimeBindingType.createIntermediary(ByNameRuntimeBindingType.java:207)

    at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.AttributeUnmarshaller.unmarshal(AttributeUnmarshaller.java:36)

    at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.UnmarshalResult.unmarshalBindingType(UnmarshalResult.java:174)

    at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.UnmarshalResult.unmarshalType(UnmarshalResult.java:212)

    at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshalType(UnmarshallerImpl.java:127)

    at weblogic.wsee.bind.runtime.internal.LiteralDeserializerContext.unmarshalType(LiteralDeserializerContext.java:70)

    at weblogic.wsee.bind.runtime.internal.BaseDeserializerContext.internalDeserializeType(BaseDeserializerContext.java:170)

    at weblogic.wsee.bind.runtime.internal.BaseDeserializerContext.deserializeType(BaseDeserializerContext.java:87)

    at weblogic.wsee.bind.runtime.internal.BaseDeserializerContext.deserializeWrappedElement(BaseDeserializerContext.java:133)

    at weblogic.wsee.codec.soap11.SoapDecoder.decodePart(SoapDecoder.java:407)

    at weblogic.wsee.codec.soap11.SoapDecoder.decodeParams(SoapDecoder.java:245)

    at weblogic.wsee.codec.soap11.SoapDecoder.decodeParts(SoapDecoder.java:164)

    at weblogic.wsee.codec.soap11.SoapDecoder.decode(SoapDecoder.java:117)

    at weblogic.wsee.codec.soap11.SoapCodec.decode(SoapCodec.java:139)

    at weblogic.wsee.ws.dispatch.server.CodecHandler.decode(CodecHandler.java:138)

    at weblogic.wsee.ws.dispatch.server.CodecHandler.handleRequest(CodecHandler.java:39)

    at weblogic.wsee.handler.HandlerIterator.handleRequest(HandlerIterator.java:127)

    at weblogic.wsee.ws.dispatch.server.ServerDispatcher.dispatch(ServerDispatcher.java:85)

    at weblogic.wsee.ws.WsSkel.invoke(WsSkel.java:80)

    at weblogic.wsee.server.servlet.SoapProcessor.handlePost(SoapProcessor.java:66)

    at weblogic.wsee.server.servlet.SoapProcessor.process(SoapProcessor.java:44)

    at weblogic.wsee.server.servlet.BaseWSServlet$AuthorizedInvoke.run(BaseWSServlet.java:173)

    at weblogic.wsee.server.servlet.BaseWSServlet.service(BaseWSServlet.java:92)

    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)

    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)

    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)

    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:283)

    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:175)

    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3231)

    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)

    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)

    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2002)

    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:1908)

    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1362)

    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)

    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:181)

Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: org.w3c.dom.Document

    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:335)

    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:303)

    at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.ClassLoadingUtils.newInstance(ClassLoadingUtils.java:135)

    ... 36 more

Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: org.w3c.dom.Document

    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:335)

    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:303)

    at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.ClassLoadingUtils.newInstance(ClassLoadingUtils.java:135)

    at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.ByNameRuntimeBindingType.createIntermediary(ByNameRuntimeBindingType.java:207)

    at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.AttributeUnmarshaller.unmarshal(AttributeUnmarshaller.java:36)

    at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.UnmarshalResult.unmarshalBindingType(UnmarshalResult.java:174)
```

Please help..

Answer (score 0):

With the **LiveCycle Workbench** you can use the **WebServices Service** to invoke other webservices.

On this website [lctips.wordpress.com](http://lctips.wordpress.com/category/webservice/) 
you can find some examples.

You can also call webservice from the form with javascript or dataconnection.
[invoking-a-web-service programmatically](http://www.avoka.com/blog/2011/02/invoking-a-web-service-from-a-smartform-programmatically/)